# Disabling the background color of the parent element under child

Tags: html, css

I need to make a border for the element that is changed by clip-path property, so I made the parent element with some background and over it child element, but I need to make transparent place under child, because child will not have any background color. Example on image. How can I make it with background of parent? Maybe any other idea to make border around my element?
[image]

```css
 .menuElement {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 44px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: white;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: transparent;
      background: black;

    }

    .deg45 {
      clip-path: polygon(97.5% 14%, 95.2% 28%, 92.9% 46%, 90.6% 62%, 88.3% 81%, 86% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);

    }

      .inside{
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        right: 1px;
        bottom: 1px;
       
        clip-path: polygon(97.5% 14%, 95.2% 28%, 92.9% 46%, 90.6% 62%, 88.3% 81%, 86% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
      
      }
```

```html
            <div class="menuElement deg45"><div class="inside">First Element</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reduce the opacity of the shape you want to make in the background and add a border

example:

```
 .menuElement {
      /* opacity level is exampel */
      opacity: 20%;

      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 44px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: white;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: transparent;
      background: black;

    }
```